# load only few files from a HDFS directory

Tags: hive

I want to load some of the files from a HDFS directory into a table.

The files in the HDFS directory as below.

```
/data/log/user1log.csv
/data/log/user2log.csv
/data/log/user3log.csv
/data/log/user4log.csv
/data/log/user5log.csv
```

Now I want to load /data/log/user1log.csv and /data/log/user2log.csv files.

I have tried the below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log_data (username string,log_dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

load data inpath '/data/log/user1log.csv' into table log_data;
load data inpath '/data/log/user2log.csv' into table log_data;
```

But after loading data into table files are vanishing from HDFS location.
But the file we should keep in the HDFS location.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, when you do `Load inpath` it moves data rather than copying.

However, you have a **External Table** so you can load data even without using `Load inpath`

Here's how you can do it.

**Specify the location for your Hive Table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log_data (username string,log_dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
location '/data/log_data/table'
```

**Copy Files to Location**

```
hdfs dfs -cp /data/log/user1log.csv /data/log_data/table/
hdfs dfs -cp /data/log/user2log.csv /data/log_data/table/
```